# RecyclerView cannot be scrolled

Tags: android

I have the problem that my recyclerView is not scrollable. I've already packed this into a NestedScrollView - same problem.
I just can't get it to show all the items and therefore be scrollable.
If I change the direction from vertical to horizontal in the LinearLayoutManager everything works. What am I doing wrong?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView .../>

 ....

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cutRv"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_cards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the single_item.xml for the RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout 
...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Initialize the RecyclerView:

```
val cutAdapter = HairCutAdapter(cutsArray,this)
val recyclerView: RecyclerView = binding.cutRv
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            ,false)
recyclerView.adapter = cutAdapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for RecyclerView and the height is equal to the height of all elements, then it can go beyond the screen and won't scroll, replace with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or set a specific height

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recycler view inside NestedScrollView then you should use

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

I hope it will help you.